Difference in live usb and base
I have booted into the official Debian live USB with debian-live-12.5.0-amd64-gnome.iso. I have changed a few settings (for example, enable touchpad's tap-to-click in system settings and Firefox's about:config) through the GNOME GUI.
How can I get the difference in the live environment (with settings changed) and debian-live-12.5.0-amd64-gnome.iso as a file list? I want the difference so that I can create my customized live USB with live-build.
